# Javascript Функция (function) привязка

Tags: javascript, функции

Это упражнение из книги "Eloquant Javascript"- я не могу понять, почему в данном коде в нижней функции printFarmInventory, срабатывает привязка, при которой латинские названия зверей выводятся в консоль на русском?

Например, printZeroPaddedWithLabel (cows, "коров")- это такой принятый синтаксис, который можно использовать при написании любой другой функции javascript (в скобках указывать слово и соответсвующее ему значение через запятую), или автор кода указал где-то это привязку и поэтому она срабатывает?

```js
function printZeroPaddedWithLabel(number, label) {
  let NumberString = String(number);
  
  while (NumberString.length < 3) {
    NumberString = '0' + NumberString
  }
  
  console.log(`${NumberString} ${label}`)
}

function printFarmInventory(cows, chicken, pigs) {
  printZeroPaddedWithLabel(cows, "коров");
  printZeroPaddedWithLabel(chicken, "цыплят");
  printZeroPaddedWithLabel(pigs, "хрюш");
}

printFarmInventory(7, 11, 23)
```

Comment: ` printZeroPaddedWithLabel (cows, "коров");` здесь передается два параметра, в первом параметре передается число, во втором название, это название и выводится в консоль.

Comment: Не ясно что за привязка. В самом низу вызывается функция, внутри которой вызывается другая функция. Всё. Никакой магии

Comment: соws это не латинское название, это имя переменной записанное латинскими буквами, за именем скрывается какое-то явное значение присвоенное ранее, переменные есть в большинстве языков

Answer (score 0):

cows, chicken, pigs - это параметры функции. Значения этих параметров были переданы тут:

```
printFarmInventory (7,11,23)
```

соответственно в cows будет значение 7, в chicken - 11 и в pigs - 23.

---

Вместо cows, chicken, pigs  могли быть произвольные имена, даже wqeytqweytu.  Просто в текущем виде они отображают то, к чему относятся